# KWIC with lucene 3.1

Tags: lucene, lucene-highlighter

I study Lucene and there's somtehing i still don't understand.
First, I use the last version of lucene, 3.1.

Then everything works fine but I keep failing to use the Highlighter and the Fragments.

Is anybody know how to use it in the last version?

Thank you and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

We are using a FastVectorHighlighter to do the highlighting. You can have a look at the implementation on GitHub:
https://github.com/Letractively/gtxcontentconnector/blob/ad4c49d250f4ce22db000426f4cf195c1b773452/contentconnector/contentconnector-lucene/src/main/java/com/gentics/cr/lucene/search/highlight/WhitespaceVectorBolder.java